# Bash script - Lookup one variable from source .csv file to provide the other

Tags: bash, csv

What we want to accomplish. Have one source file (data.csv) to be referenced with the following data:

```
userone,password1 
usertwo,password2 
userthree,password3
```

Use the source file to find a username and then provide the password after the comma as another variable.
Example

```
Variables:
User1=userone
User1Password=password1

#!/usr/bin/env bash
source data.csv
read data.csv
If $User1=userone
    then
$User1Password=password1
```

- We are using this to create a local user account on a Mac with a different line of code but need to reference a .csv file to get the variables.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`

```
user=userone
pass=$(awk -F, -v user="$user" '$1 == user { print $2; exit }' data.csv)
```

`-F,` sets the field separator to comma. `-v user="user"` sets the `awk` variable from the `bash` variable. `$1` and `$2` are the contents of those fields of the CSV.

Comment: Barmar,  Thank you for the quick reply. When using your script the $pass variable produces "user2" when I add echo $pass. Which is the next line item in column one.  We want to print what is after the comma on the same line, i.e  "password1".  Do you have another suggestion?  We are looking on our end.  Thanks for getting us in the right direction.

Comment: I just tried it and `echo $pass` shows `password1`. I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Make sure `data.csv` doesn't use CRLF as its line break. If you created the file on Windows, use `dos2unix` to convert it to Unix format.

Comment: You are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

```
cat data.csv | \                                         # piping file contents to the loop
while read line; do                                      # reading the input stream line by line
    username=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $1}')      # username is the 1st string if a , is the delimiter
    password=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $2}')      # password is the 2nd string if a , is the delimiter
    echo ${username} ${password}                         # test
done
```

Comment: This should be `while IFS=, read username password; do echo "$username" "$password"; done < data.csv`. No pipe, no unnecessary `awk` processes.

Comment: You could also use `cut` instead of `awk`, it's simpler.